# Drag and Drop (javascript) breaks after first drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

So, what it does: You can successfully drag something anywhere, but when you click it again, it resets to its original position (I don't know why), and when you try to drag it again, as soon as your cursor touches the object it disappears (I don't know why). I'm hoping someone can tell me why it is happening and how to fix it!

```
// JavaScript Document

var posX;
var posY;
var element;

function drag() {

element = document.getElementById("square");
posX = event.clientX;
posY = event.clientY;

element.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
}

function move() {

    element.addEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);

    element.style.left = event.clientX - posX + "px";
    element.style.top = event.clientY - posY + "px";
}

function drop() {

    element.removeEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
    element.removeEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
}
```

the html is a simple (position is set to relative):

`<p id="square" onmousedown="drag(event)">`meep`</p>`

Lastly, and most importantly, thank you all for your time =]

Comment: While it's perfectly valid to roll-your-own, jQuery UI has battle tested Draggable and Droppable plugins that make this sort of thing easier.

Comment: (Said in another comment)
This was my first attempt (ever) at making something in javascript. Before I learn how to use a library, I would like to learn how to use the basic language. (I learn when I make things.)

Comment: It's not just JavaScript you have to learn, but working around cross-browser incompatibilities as well. Check the amount of workarounds sprinkled in here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js So if you really want to go without using Draggable and Droppable, I'd recommend you at least use jquery.ui.mouse as a solid foundation that works across browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
posX = event.clientX;
posY = event.clientY;
```

The problem is these values are always set to the offset of the click from the top of the body, NOT from the top of the square element. The first time they worked fine, because the offset from the top of the body was the same thing as that of the element, because its position was right up against the body. Once you moved it, it would have the offset from the side of the body from wherever you just moved it to. When you dragged it with the mouse, it would move it with the mouse's position *shifted over the number of pixels you just moved it to.* This often moved it completely off the screen. You want the element to move with the mouse where the top of the element stays in the same position relative to the mouse.

If this doesn't make sense, post a comment and I'll try to make it a little clearer. :D

This worked for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// JavaScript Document

var posX;
var posY;
var element;

function drag(event) {                //added event parameter

element = document.getElementById("square");
posX = event.clientX - parseInt(  element.offsetLeft );  //this is the big change!
posY = event.clientY - parseInt(  element.offsetTop );

element.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
}

function move(event) {                  //added event parameter
    if (typeof(document.getElementById("square").mouseup) == "undefined") {  //this just prevents redundantly adding the same event handler repeatedly, even though duplicates are removed anyway
        element.addEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    }

    element.style.left = event.clientX - posX + "px";
    element.style.top = event.clientY - posY + "px";
}

function drop() {

    element.removeEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
    element.removeEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: blue;
 }

p {
 position: relative; 
 background-color: red;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 left: 1px;
 top: 1px;
}

</style>
<body>
<p id="square" onmousedown="drag(event)">meep</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added a quick debug test, and posX and posY are storing values. I got the logic from numerous tutorials I skimmed through when getting the position of the cursor ect.

I added the parameter, but the issue still persists. Once I fix this issue, I will re-write the code to use the ondrag() event, but I still have no idea why it is happening. Also, I will try and add cross-browser compatibility once I get it working in one of them =p

Comment: Thanks for adding in the if statement in the move() function. Now I understand what you meant. Makes a lot of sense. However, when I added the changes to the posX and posY variables, the drag and drop no longer works.

Comment: @Dbz whoops, my bad for using dynamic css methods that don't work in mozilla. I've changed it to a mozilla solution. If you want something cross browser almost any good js framework will have the capability. :D

Comment: clientX/clientY doesn't give you the offset from the top of the body, but from the top of the browser's current view port. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.clientY

Answer (score 0):

This answer might earn me a downvote, but what the heck. Have you thought of using jQuery and the jQuery UI library. They have a really nice working drag and drop: [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). This might be easier to use then trying figure it out on your own.

Comment: This was my first attempt (ever) at making something in javascript. Before I learn how to use a library, I would like to learn how to use the basic language. (I learn when I make things.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function drag(element) {
    element.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
    element.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
}
```

.

```
<p id="square" ondrag="drag(this);" ondragend="drag(this);">meep</p>
```

Comment: Hello! I greatly appreciate the fix, but I still don't know the source of the problem =/

Comment: one problem i can see in your code is that every time you press down the p-tag you call drag-function and drag-function attach event listener every time. You only need to attach a event on a element once.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to make the drag and drop work without adding in a onmousemove="function" or ondrag="function" into the `<p>`.